# Moving CDN jQuery to footer does not work?

Tags: functions, jquery, footer, cdn

What I want to achieve:

- Change the default JS to Google's CDN --> *this works*
- **Move the Google CDN to the footer --> this does not work**

My code:

```
function my_init()   
{  
    if (!is_admin())   
    {  
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');  

        // Load a copy of jQuery from the Google API CDN  
        // The last parameter set to TRUE states that it should be loaded  
        // in the footer.  
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', FALSE, '1.11.0', TRUE);  

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  
    }  
}  
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

I read that the last "TRUE", means that it's added to the footer. It's also stated in *The Codex*, so it must be true. When I check my page source, however, it shows the `Google CDN` in the head and not in the footer, as I wanted to.

My question: what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I *could* be mistaken but if any scripts ( plugin, theme, or otherwise ) is dependant on JQuery and is enqueued into the header, jquery will also be thrown into the header above that script.

Comment: Following what @Howdy_McGee said, https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ might show you what is dependent on 'jquery' when the scripts are rendered. Be careful that you don't have any inline scripts that require jQuery to be present.